# How do you allow index.php in .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

At present, the .htaccess file will mask dynamic links with static links e.g. **www.example.com/news/news.php?article=foo-bar** will read as **www.example.com/news/foo-bar/**.

However, if I wanted to open **www.example.com/news/** instead of **www.example.com/news/index.php**, it still redirects it to **www.example.com/news/news.php** e.g. adding **?article=index** on the end.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /news/news.php?article=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem,
your REGEX should be `^news/(.+)$` instead of `^news/(.*)$`.

`+` means one or more
`*` means zero or more

Comment: Oh yay!
Feel free to mark my answer as accepted to close the topic if you don't have anymore problem! <3